# ¿Como obtener la hora y fecha actual de un pais en PHP?

Tags: php, date

Quiero obtener la hora y fecha actual de Perú. este es mi codigo

```
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Lima'); 
echo date("g:i A");
```

El problema es que cuando cambio la hora de mi sistema, también cambia en mi pagina, lo que yo quiero es que no coja la hora del sistema, sino la hora de internet.

Comment: Aquí tienes una pregunta parecida donde te indica como hacer una query a un servidor NTP y obtener la hora de una determinada zona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592142/retrieve-time-from-ntp-server-via-php

Answer (score 1):

## EXPLICACIÓN

La "hora de internet" es un término que usa la gente pero no es correcto. Internet es una red compuesta por miles de millones de servidores cada uno con una hora distinta... lo que puedes hacer es pedirle la hora a un servidor especifico, para esto se usa un servicio y una llamada cURL

Necesitas:

1. Primero encuentra un WS (Web Service) confiable que te devuelva la hora que necesitas (puedes hacer el tuyo)
2. Haz un PHP con una llama cURL https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.curl.php
3. Imprime la hora

Si vas a poner la hora en un front-end web es más amigable usar jquery en especifico AJAX para hacer la llamada.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

## OPCIÓN cURL

### Diagrama

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Código CURL

Ejemplo de código para consumir el servicio de worldtimeapi.org

```
//INITIALIZE Curl
$ch_n = curl_init();
//SET Curl OPTIONS
//conection values
curl_setopt($ch_n, CURLOPT_URL, "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Salta");
//expected answer - true
curl_setopt($ch_n, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//EXECUTE Curl call and save answer
$answer = curl_exec($ch_n);
//PRINT answer 
print_r($answer);
//CLOSE CONECTION
curl_close($ch_n);
```

## OPCIÓN AJAX

### Diagrama

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Código JS

Usando la librería JQuery se pueden hacer llamadas con el método AJAX, existen varias versiones como post() o get() pero en este caso usaré la general. Probablemente sea mejor usar get, revisa la documentación.

```
$.ajax({ //Define options
    method: "GET", //http method
    url: "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Salta",
    dataType: "json", //Expected answer type
})
.done(function(data){ //When call is done..
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Le recomiendo que haga lo siguiente:

1) Vaya a su página phpinfo () y busque el archivo de configuración cargado y abra el archivo php.ini.

2) Cambie la configuración predeterminada de la zona horaria agregando su nueva zona horaria modificando esta línea: date.timezone = America/Lima.

3) Guarde el archivo php.ini y detenga el servidor Apache.

4) Reinicie el servidor Apache. La configuración de la zona horaria ahora debe modificarse.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello vas a necesitar implementar esta linea de código al principio e indicar tu **continente** y **ciudad**

```html
date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
```

Comment: Eso le daría la hora basado en su sistema operativo y eso no es lo que busca el OP